# How this jQuery namespace (JavaScript) works?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery.namespace = function() {
    var a = arguments, o = null, i, j, d;
    for( i = 0; i < a.length; i = i + 1) {
        d = a[i].split(".");
        o = window;
        for( j = 0; j < d.length; j = j + 1) {
            o[d[j]] = o[d[j]] || {};
            o = o[d[j]];
        }
    }
    return o;
};

jQuery.namespace("com.fc");
```

I came across some JS code and can't figure out how this works & what it does. You call the function with a string but function doesn't take anything? What is the purpose of whole thing?

Comment: You can get the parameter as `arguments`.

Comment: @Matt that _is_ unobfuscated ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arguments` is a keyword in javascript that is an array-like object containing all the arguments passed to a function.

The function loops over each argument, and assumes that each is a string. It then splits the string on '.' and creates the deep object represented by that dot-notation.

Consider an empty object `{}`. This function operating on this object with the argument `"com.fc"` would become:

```
{
    com: {
        fc: {
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, that original object is `window`, so it creates an empty object within window using the string as the dot-notation guide of how to walk deep into the object.

Answer (score 3):

arguments is an array of all the arguments passed to the function

in the case of

`jQuery.namespace("com.fc");`

arguments[0] would be "com.fc"

it appears to loop over all the arguments, and split the namespace by "."

then attempts to traverse a window object for the namespaces creating a hash finally it returns the depest level hash.

Looks like this function could be used to set a namespaced variable in the deep hash using the walking..

jQuery.namespace("com.fc").something = "yo"

or if the namespace is already populated with data or funcitons

```
jQuery.namespace("com.fc").somefunction();
jQuery.namespace("com.fc").somevalue;
```

Not sure why the gymnastics of allowing multiple namespaces as it could only return what would seemingly be the last.